# Discord.js anti-spam save user data

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make an anti-spam in Discord.js. But I can't figure out how to save data such as the time the user last sent a message, etc..

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? What part of saving the data are you struggling with? Is it figuring out what data to save, what format to save it in or even where to save it?

Comment: How to save it to the memory. So i can look up ex when the user last sent an message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every message object in Discord.js has a `author` attribute and a `createdAt` attribute that you can use to figure out who sent a messsage and when it was sent. The `author` object stored inside the `author` attribute also contains an `id` attribute which is unique for every discord member. I believe the timestamp is also a UNIX Epoch timestamp meaning that the value is the number of milliseconds since `January 1, 1970`

Potentially you could use a simple map to keep track of when a person sent their last message where the key of that map would be the authors id and the value would be the `createdAt` timestamp.

The map you use would, therefore, look a bit like this:

```
{
    '266241948824764416': 1554400076,
    '266241948824757956': 1554401204
}
```

Then when you receive future messages you can just lookup the users ID from the map you created and then subtract the value you get from the map from the `createdAt` timestamp in the new message to get the number of milliseconds since the users last message.

I can recommend that you look at the Discord.js API docs for reference https://discord.js.org

Comment: :/ But i need to store multiple types of info. So something like a json like thing would be better.

Comment: That's not a problem, you can store maps inside of maps.


{
    '266241948824764416': {'lastSentMessage': 1554400076, 'username': 'Ashleigh Carr'},
    '266241948824757956': {'lastSentMessage': 155441200076, 'username': 'SomeRandomSkid'}
}

Comment: JSON is a format used for storing data on a disk and/or transfering data between applications, not something that should be used inside an application. Its basically a way of representing data with text.